# Pagination difficulty using custom query in genesis-based custom theme

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a genesis child theme.  I have a category called 'faculty' with about 60 posts in it.  I am modifying the category template file so that it displays this category in a customized fashion.

The desired result is that

- the faculty appear in random order,
- they do not appear more than once
- they appear in groups of four per page

Here is the relevant code from my page:

```
remove_action('genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop');
add_action('genesis_loop', 'hdo_faculty_loop');

function hdo_faculty_loop() {
  global $paged;
  $args = array(
    'category_name' => 'faculty',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'paged' => $paged
  );
  genesis_custom_loop(  $args );

}

genesis();
```

What I am getting is http://hdo.la.utexas.edu/category/faculty/:

- 4 faculty per page [yay!]
- random order [yay!]
- previous and next navigation at the bottom of the page [yay!]
- only 6 pages (24 faculty) instead of the expected 15 [boo!]
- duplicate faculty in the set of 24 [boo]
- a "next" loop on the sixth page that navigates to a 404

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? I have a similar situation and I'm getting a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same problem as you, and I found a solution to this matter.
Go to WP settings, under "reading", and update the 'posts_per_page' value also in there. It's set to 10 by default.
I hope it helps!
Regards.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I don't think that will work for me.  The posts_per_page value you are talking about is a global default.  For the rest of my site I want that value to be 10.  It is just on this query that I want it to be 4.  If I do as you say, I'll end up with pages of 4 posts on every page on my site.

Comment: Vlasits, I'm not sure, but I think that this only affects to the front page. I have also other post type archives, and they are not affected by this parameter.